# Area of $\Delta ABC$ via $2$ statements

Tags: geometry

> What is the area of the $\Delta ABC$? 
> Ι. $∠BAC = 45°$. 
> ΙΙ. $AC = 16 cm$ and $BC = 12 cm$. 
>
> (A)  question can be answered using  only one of the statements alone.  
> (B)  question can be answered using either statement alone.  
> (C)  question can be answered using Ι and ΙΙ together but not using Ι or ΙΙ alone.  
> (D)  question cannot be answered even using Ι and ΙΙ together.

My Approach:

> Let $AB=x$. Then, I used the Cosine formula: $Cos A = \frac {b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$
> $Cos (45°)= \frac {16^2+x^2-12^2}{2(16x)}$
> $\Rightarrow \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}= \frac {256+x^2-144}{2(16x)}$
> $\Rightarrow x^2-16\sqrt 2x+112=0$
> $\Rightarrow x=8\sqrt 2 \pm 4=AB$
> Since I'm getting 2 possible triangles, so I can't distinctly find the area of the triangle.
> Thus, (D).

Solution given:

> From I and II, we have $∠BAC = 45°, AC = 16 cm, BC = 12 cm$. 
> [image: Diag]
>
>  Let $D$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$. 
> $AB = AD + DB$ 
> $=CD+ \sqrt {{BC}^2-{CD}^2}=8\sqrt 2+\sqrt {{12}^2-{(8\sqrt 2)}^2}$ 
> $=8\sqrt 2 +4$ 
> Area of $\Delta ABC = \frac 12 (AB)(CD)$
> $CD = AC Sin 45° = \frac {16}{\sqrt 2}=8\sqrt 2 ≃ 11.3 cm. \text { Sufficient.} $
> Thus, option (C) is correct.

Could it be that the answer (thus, solution) given is wrong? Or am I making mistake somewhere? Please help.

Comment: Yea, I agree that there are two different triangles. To be complete, maybe also mention that the areas of these triangles are different. (D)

Comment: Apparently whoever wrote the answer key needs a refresher in what combinations of angles and sides determine a triangle. Angle-side-side is generally not one of them. Here we have two triangles with the same altitude $CD$ but different base sides $AB.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that your work is correct, make the following construction:

1. Construct $AC=16 cm$.
2. Draw a line $\ell$ through $A$, inclined at an angle $45^{\circ}$ to $AC$.
3. With center C, draw a circle $\Sigma$ of radius $12 cm$. You’ll notice that $\Sigma$ intersects $\ell$ at two points. These are the two possible positions of the point B. [image]

In the image, the triangle $\triangle ABC$ corresponds to the solution provided to you. They have assumed that the foot of perpendicular D lies between A and B, or in other words, they have taken $\angle B$ to be acute.

Obviously, the two triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle AB”C$ have different areas, so the conclusion of option D follows.

Also, to understand the algebraic solution of $8\sqrt 2\color{red}\pm 4$, imagine a perpendicular dropped from C to BB”. D bisects BB” and note that $AC=8\sqrt2,$ while $\color{blue}{B”D=BD=4}$. Thus $AB”=8\sqrt2-4$ while $AB=8\sqrt2+4$.

Comment: Wow! thank you for tremendous efforts. Upvoted. To add, I simply did this to check my result: 1. Triangle property $a+b>c$ is followed and 2. Triangle has different areas. 3. For diagram, here's what I did: drew 2 separate $∠BAC = 45$ deg. Then, in one I extended 1 arm and then joined the open ends so that $∠C$ is obtuse now and in the other one, I drew one arm of the angle short s.t. now $∠C$ was acute. Very roughly to scale. (Note 1: step 3 in not necessary ) (Note 2: Step 1 and 2 are evident from the values themselves)

Comment: “Step 3 is not necessary “: it’s not “ _not necessary_ ”,  it is just an alternative way to see the same thing. It would be “ _not necessary_” if we could infer the existence of two triangles from just 1 and 2, without any extra steps. Thanks fir the upvote By the way.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Also, @insipidintegrator, sometimes I also need to provide such figures/diagrams for explanation or while asking a question so, could you please tell me the software that you used. (Even better if its online.)

Comment: Yes it’s online: I use [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry). I draw the figure, take screenshots and upload. I’ve heard of a person using The Geometer’s Sketchpad, but I’m not sure: it may need to be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Will try it. Also looking on meta for such posts.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if point B is between $A$ and $D$? In this case, $AB \ne AD +DB$. I believe you are correct, there are two possible triangles. The triangle with sides $16, 12, 8\sqrt 2 -4$ does exist.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Upvoted.

Comment: @InanimateBeing: Thanks! Nice work on the question.

Comment: Thank you for the encouraging remark :-)